# Comparing excel files using a primary key and displaying the difference in a new dataframe

Tags: python, excel, difference

I have two excel sheets which have different number of columns and rows
They have a unique key = ‘ID’
I am trying to compare each of the columns in the excel files and where ever there is a mismatch; Im trying to display the difference of that column

```
Dataset1:

ID  Amt Orders  Name
AB_1    33.4    10  TBC
CD_2    56.5    20  TBC1

Dataset2:
ID  Amt Orders  Name
AB_1    50  11  TBC
CD_2    60  211 TBC1


Results:
ID  Amt_1   Amt_2   Diff
AB_1    50  33.4    16.6
CD_2    60  56.5    3.5
```

I tried below solutions: I feel that they are not the right fit for me
:https://pbpython.com/excel-diff-pandas-update.html

How Do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the difference yourself it if it is always the same format. It is a bit strange to call amt_1 the amt from dataset2 but I kept it like you described.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

pathFolder_to_file = '*yourpath*'  

# define the types of the columns
df_dtypes = {'ID': str,'Amt': np.float,'Orders': np.float,'Name': str}

df1 = pd.read_excel(io = pathFolder_to_file + '/dataset1.xlsx', dtype = df_dtypes, index_col="ID")
df2 = pd.read_excel(io = pathFolder_to_file + '/dataset2.xlsx', dtype = df_dtypes, index_col="ID")

# inner join assumes that df1 and df2 have the same ID in them
df = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_1', lsuffix = '_2')
df["Diff"] = df["Amt_1"] - df["Amt_2"]

# filter out all records where there is no difference and print
diff_df = df[df["Diff"] != 0]
print(diff_df[["Amt_1", "Amt_2", "Diff"]])
```